# How to host a ASP .NET website on Android?

Tags: android, asp.net, apache, http

I want to host an asp .net web site on my phone. Is there any other library that will allow me to host .asp pages by an Android application running a Web Server(e.g. nanohttpd) in the background?

Is there any mod/plugin like "mod_aspdotnet for PC" which can be integrated in an Android app?

I did a lot of research but couldn't find a solution to this. Please guide me.

Comment: Assuming for the moment that there's a legitimate reason to do it that way, there's not much to stop you from compiling Apache and its modules in a cross-compiler for ARM and bundling them up using NDK. The effort required is probably much more than the effort of removing ASP from the equation. Who would be the consumer of the web site running on, say, a 1GHz machine with half a GiB of RAM and a low-speed Internet link with a dynamic address?

Comment: Actually I want to use the server locally. I guess I'll have to drop the idea for now. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting the functionality in Android-flavoured Java or JavaScript or something that doesn't require a huge external stack of applications will probably get you better results relative to time invested …